# Bosonic operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator

We have a vector of bosonic operators, such that:
\begin{equation*}
\vec{\phi} = (a, b, c)^{\text{T}} \; ,
\end{equation*}
and the following commutation rules,
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
[A_{\ell}, A_{\ell^{'}}] &=0 \\
[A^{\dagger}_{\ell}, A^{\dagger}_{\ell^{'}}] &=0 \\
[A_{\ell}, A^{\dagger}_{\ell^{'}}] &=\delta_{\ell,\ell^{'}} \; ,
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
for each operator, where $A_{\ell} = a,b,c$.

If now we applied a rotation to the vector, such that:
\begin{equation*}
\vec{\phi^{'}} = R^{-1}\vec{\phi} \; ,
\end{equation*}
where:

$R = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 1 & \sqrt{2} \\
\sqrt{2} & \sqrt{2} & 0 \\
-1 & 1 & -\sqrt{2} 
\end{bmatrix}$ and
$R^{-1} = \frac{1}{2} \begin{bmatrix}
-1 & \sqrt{2} & -1 \\
1 & \sqrt{2} & 1 \\
\sqrt{2} & 0 & -\sqrt{2}  
\end{bmatrix} = R^{\dagger} \; ,$

[**EDIT**: the matrix $R$ had a typo and wasn't unitary. Where it reads $1/2$, it was $1/\sqrt{2}$.]

are the new operators also bosonic?
**Is this type of linear combination of bosonic operators also a bosonic operator?**

Comment: You wrote down the conditions for operators to be bosonic. Did you try to straightforwardly check if your new operators fulfil those conditions?

Comment: What is the connection between the ${\boldsymbol \phi}$ and the $A$'s? And why write the inverse of the orthogonal matrix $Ri$ n such a strange way? It's just the transpose of $R$ surely?

Comment: The vector $\phi$ is formed by three bosonic operators $a$, $b$ and $c$. They follow these three conditions, where $Aℓ=a,b,c$. The matrix $R$ was given like that, so the operation $RR^{\dagger}=2\mathbb{I}$, that might be the source of the issue here. Thank you.

Comment: Tip: [Let's not have posts look like revision histories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/2451).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written it, $R$ is not unitary nor orthogonal, as $$RR^\dagger=R^\dagger R=2\mathbb{I}.$$ Using the proper normalization for $R$ (with $1/2$ out front instead of $1/\sqrt{2}$) will ensure that it is unitary and thus that the resulting operators will also satisfy bosonic commutation relations.

Comment: Apparently the question provides an incorrect rotation matrix. I was thinking that something else would be needed if that wasn't the issue. Thank you.

Comment: @yko awesome, glad to help!